# Install Python pycryptodome libraries for Apache Spark in Azure Synapse

Tags: python, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am tying to install pycryptodome to azure synapse notebook. PFB details.

**`scenario -`** I have created a notebook and Apache spark pool in azure synapse. I used the Below command to list the packages installed on pool. I don't see my required packages in the list. So I tried to install it using requirement.txt file and requirement.yml file in package section of Apache spark pool.

**steps performed-**

pip list : command to see the packages already installed.

created below file and uploaded in package section of Apache Spark pool.

**requirement.txt:**

pycryptodome==3.16.0

**requirement.yml code:**

```
name: pycrypto_lib

channels:

-defaults
dependencies:

-pip:
 -pycryptodome
```

**error=** PFA screenshot

[image]
please share your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install `pycryptodome`. Follow the below steps:

*Go to  **Manage** -> Go to **Apache Spark pool** -> **select Packages** -> **upload package_file.txt** -> apply.*

> Note: inside package_file.txt make sure to mention your package name:
> `pycryptodome==3.16.0`

[image]

[image]

*I tested on my environment successfully installed `pycryptodome==3.16.0`*

[image]

*To verify package version. Follow below code:*

```
import pkg_resources
for d in pkg_resources.working_set:
    print(d)
```

***You can check Successfully package installed:***

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this option already, but somehow the Conda environment which is using Spark pool for this notebook execution is messed up and not working with Requirements.txt file. So I am able to make it working with Pycryptodome Linux .whl file and uploaded into Workspace Packages.